# Please resolve the error

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d WHERE d.apt='KOPF' AND d.name!=d.trans  

LEFT OUTER JOIN  

(SELECT distinct c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c  
    INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type  
     FROM corept.std_star_leg  
     WHERE data_supplier='J' AND airport_ident='KOPF'  
     group by star_ident,transition_ident)b  
    ON c.sequence_num=b.seq and c.star_ident=b.star_ident and   c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident) as y  
ON c.sid_ident=x.name AND c.fix_ident=x.trans  
where y.data_supplier='J' and y.airport_ident='KOPF' and y.name is null;
```

While executing the above query i am getting the following syntax error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LEFT OUTER JOIN
>
> (SELECT distinct c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_sta' at line
>   3

I used left join so that i could get the data differences from the above two queries.I had even placed the where condition last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One good technique for finding the error is to break it down and try the components separately.  For example, try:

```
SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type  
FROM corept.std_star_leg  
WHERE data_supplier='J' AND airport_ident='KOPF'  
group by star_ident,transition_ident
```

to see if this is any problem with that subquery.

When a query has no syntax error, but does not produce the expected results, breaking down the query into understandable pieces is usually the fastest way to debug it.

Comment: I had already gone thru dat...both the queiries run fine individually..but when i combine them using left join..there is a prblm again :(

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your error is the invalid use of `LEFT JOIN`. The basic `SELECT` syntax is as follows,

```
SELECT ...
FROM ... JOIN...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY...
ORDER BY ...
```

You have used `LEFT JOIN` after the `WHERE` clause which causes syntax error.